# how to set sql data for charts in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

How to create bar chart using SQL server database. Below my c# code.

```
double[] yValues = { 10, 15};
string[] xNames = { "Available", "NotAvailable" };
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, yValues);
```

This is my SQL server database table. I want to create bar chart using this table.

```
+----+---------------+
| id | SeatBookStatus| 
+----+---------------+
| 01 |    Yes        |
| 02 |    No         |
| 03 |    No         |
| 04 |    No         |
| 05 |    No         |
+----+---------------+
```

Comment: Are you looking for the SQL to read the data from the database? Maybe: `select count(id), SeatBookStatus from sometable group by SeatBookStatus;` ?

Comment: @TaW, Actually, I want to know, how to write c# code my friend. Thank you.

Comment: Well, what you have is correct and working code code.

Comment: i want show data using microsoft SQL server

Comment: So? Did you get the data from it?? Whereto did you read them?

Comment: Yes, Got DATa..